# How to change background color of row in datagrid in wpf?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I want to change the background of row in datagrid if the value of a row item exceeds a certain value.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113822/conditional-formatting-in-wpf-toolkit-datagrid) is the way to do it without resorting to procedural code, directly in XAML, which is where styling belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `LoadingRow` event, like so:

```
private void dataGridLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    YourObject rowContext = e.Row.DataContext as YourObject;

    if (rowContext != null)
    {
        if (rowContext.YourValue > _someValue)
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It breaks MVVM by introducing application logic in the code behind the view.

Comment: yes, this is not the best way for this problem because of mvvm, and the original asker should use triggers, but I like having different implementations for completness.

Comment: inefficient implementations do not contribute to completeness in any way. Consider the refactor effort required if he would have bought a third party control suite (such as DX or Infragistics or Telerik) and wanted to replace the standard WPF DataGrid for a new one.